# How to take multiple nonadjacent rows or columns that are evenly spaced in an array in Python?

Tags: python

Say I have a 10 * 10 array x. In Matlab, I can achieve strided access using code such as `x(1 : 3 : 7, 2 : 4 ：10)`. How can I do the same thing in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: The only way you get direct support for this sort of operation is using third party extensions, e.g. `numpy` `array`s. Python built-ins don't have a concept of multidimensional structures; it's composable (so you can have a structure of structures and work with each layer independently), but not specialized to multidimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy

```
import numpy as np

simple_array = np.arange(6)
print(simple_array)

# array[startIndex : endIndex : stepValue]*
print(simple_array[1:5:2])

# if you want to include the last value, you need to go above it
print(simple_array[1:6:2])

# obtain the first n-elements using array[:n]. Note that the n-th element isn't included
print(simple_array[:4])

# or the elements after that with array[n:]. Note that the n-th element is included
print(simple_array[4:])

# use step value with array[::n]
print(simple_array[::2])

# this will return the columns 3-5, with 5 not being included
print(simple_array[3:5])

# here we start at column 1, with a step of 2
print(simple_array[1::2])
```

This will output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[0, 2, 4]
[3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Works with charm! Thanks a lot!